# Скрытые блоки в slider Swiper

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

У меня есть слайдер, который я подключил с помощью библиотеки  swiper,  так же я написал скрипт, у которого есть 3 кнопки, при нажатии на первую отображается все элементы с классами block2 и block3, при нажатии на вторую кнопку, отображаются только элементы block2, когда я нажимаю на 3 кнопку отображаются все элементы  с классом block3, у меня проблема что когда я нажимаю к примеру на кнопку 3, слайдер скрывает все элементы с классом block3 но слайдер продолжает прокручивать скрытые элементы, с вертикальной версией такой проблемы нет, так же данный слайдер начинает работать только в адаптивной версии

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    var width = window.innerWidth
    if (width < 1024) {
        var newnewswiper = new Swiper('.slider_mega', {
            navigation: {
                nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
                prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
              },
            speed: 1500,

            autoplay: {
                delay: 3000,
                disableOnInteraction: true,
            },
        });
    }
})
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На скриншоте показано что при нажатой кнопки номер 2, слайдер продолжает прокручиваться хотя элементы с классном block3 скрыты (display: none;)

Html код не могу предоставить, так как он огромный.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При нажатии кнопок скрывающих/показывающих слайды - обновляйте слайдер `newnewswiper.update()`. При необходимости и другие методы методы для пересчета слайдера - [документация и методы swiper](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#methods--properties)

Comment: Спасибо большое, для тех кто будет это читать, не забудьте объявить глобальную переменную